# Archivo descargado con download.file no se puede abrir en excel (R)

Tags: r, excel

Holi, estoy intentando descargar un archivo de una página usando R. Mi código es:

```
archivo = GET("https://api.cafci.org.ar/estadisticas/descargar/informacion/diaria/2/2021-11-10")
file_destino = "C:\\Users\\rbisa\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\a.xlsx"
download.file(archivo$url, file_destino)
```

El file se descarga y se crea el archivo, pero cuando lo abro recibo el error:

> Excel cannot open the file because the format file or file extension
> is not valid. Verify that the file extension matches the format of the
> file

Ambos archivos son xlsx, y cuando lo descargo manualmente puedo abrirlo bien. Alguna idea de que puede estar sucediendo?

Answer (score 4):

No necesitas descargar el archivo en tu pc. Puedes cargarlo directamente a R. Como es un archivo xlsx. Puedes usar la función `read.xlsx()`.

```
library(openxlsx)
df<-read.xlsx("https://api.cafci.org.ar/estadisticas/descargar/informacion/diaria/2/2021-11-10")
```

Con eso obtienes tu archivo de datos.

Comment: Me sirvió perfecto, era mas fácil. Muchisimas gracias!